# Error while importing data with foreign keys in django import-export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have implemented importing data using django import-export library. When i try to import data with names of object that do not exists it throws error *matching query does not exist*.

It ends with generating template with error stack trace like this:

```py
Line number: 1 - CustomUser matching query does not exist.
sample@sample.com, data1, firstname, secondname
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 520, in import_row
self.import_obj(instance, row, dry_run)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 385, in import_obj
self.import_field(field, obj, data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 368, in import_field
field.save(obj, data, is_m2m)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 110, in save
cleaned = self.clean(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 66, in clean
value = self.widget.clean(value, row=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/import_export/widgets.py", line 364, in clean
return self.get_queryset(value, row, *args, **kwargs).get(**{self.field: val})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 408, in get
self.model._meta.object_name
accounts.models.CustomUser.DoesNotExist: CustomUser matching query does not exist.
```

Custom resouce import class:

```py
class UserResourceImport(resources.ModelResource):
    """ Resource class for import utilities """

    # set foreign key relations for model, this way we can provide name instead of id
    custom_user = fields.Field(column_name='custom_user',
                      attribute='custom_user', 
                      widget=ForeignKeyWidget(CustomUser, 'name'))


    class Meta:
        model = user_model
        fields = ('email','custom_user','first_name','last_name')
        skip_unchanged = False
        report_skipped = True
        export_order = ('email', 'custom_user', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        import_id_fields = ['email']
```

Every other error of importing will result in generation of following template:
[Normal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx41M.png)

Is there any way to handle this error so it won't print stack trace into the import template and skip row with invalid data?

Comment: For those looking for similar problems, can refer to the git issues for Django import export
https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/1395

Comment: to hide stack trace, refer to [this post](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/1257#issuecomment-952276485)